# How to reference static member variables from a struct within another class

Tags: c++, struct, reference

I'm trying to define some static constant strings in C++ and reference them from different files.

Here's how I have the information set up this far:

structClass.h

```
namespace test {
     typedef struct customstructure{
          static const std::string stringA;
      } customstructure;
}
```

structClass.cpp

```
namespace test {
     static const std::string customstructure::stringA = "This is String A";
}
```

Now I'm wondering how I would call this in a third file?

execute.cpp

```
void printStringA(){
    printf("stringA is: %s", test::customstructure::stringA.c_str());
}
```

gives me a compile error that says:

undefined reference to 'test::customstructure::stringA'

Comment: You don't need the `static` before the definition of the member.

Comment: `undefined reference` errors come from the linker, not the compiler, and indicate the you failed to include `structClass.cpp` in your link.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
namespace test {
     static const std::string customstructure::stringA = "This is String A";
}
```

remove the word `static`. In fact it is an error to have this, your compiler should give a more useful error message (although I suppose 'undefined reference' meets the requirements of "a diagnostic").

Standard reference: `[class.static.data]#5` says that static data members have external linkage, however using the keyword `static` in the definition would specify internal linkage.